# SQL Subtracting dates/time's into one value

Tags: sql, db2

I have several columns:

```
|  Start             |   END              |  Duration
2008-06-28 18.03.55 | 2008-10-06 01.33.55 |  End - Start
```

My code looks like this:

```
SELECT theDelivery,
(char(theDelivery) || ' ' || char(current time)) AS Begin,
(char(theDelivery + 100 DAYS) || ' ' || char(current time + 7 HOURS + 30 MINUTES)) AS End
```

Here is what i thought about doing the subtraction... But its wrong. I know you cant subtract alias' Any thoughts?
((char(current time + 7 HOURS + 30 MINUTES) -(char(theDelivery + 100 DAYS)))

---

So i figured out i was going all wrong with char's. I came up with this and it was exactly what i was looking for:

```
SELECT theDelivery,
TIMESTAMP(theDelivery, current time) AS Begin
,
TIMESTAMP((theDelivery + 100 DAYS), (current time + 7 HOURS + 30 MINUTES)) AS End,
TIMESTAMP((theDelivery + 100 DAYS), (current time + 7 HOURS + 30 MINUTES)) - TIMESTAMP(theDelivery, current time) AS MyDur
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

((char(current time + 7 HOURS + 30 MINUTES) -(char(theDelivery + 100 DAYS)))

You are substracting chars. You can try:

```
date( 
  to_date(
      char(current time + 7 HOURS + 30 MINUTES),
      'YYYY-MM-DD HH.MI.SS'
  ) 
) -
date(
   to_date(
      char(theDelivery + 100 DAYS),
      'YYYY-MM-DD HH.MI.SS'
   )
)
```

Or in a sigle line:

```
date( to_date( char(current time + 7 HOURS + 30 MINUTES),'YYYY-MM-DD HH.MI.SS' ) ) - date( to_date(char(theDelivery + 100 DAYS),'YYYY-MM-DD HH.MI.SS') )
```

Comment: Please note that the result will be _imprecise_, and **not** in an exact number of anything.

Comment: Check the Edit i made underneath my original question!